# Dataflow WordCount hangs when uploading to GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm following Google's Dataflow quickstart: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python and I think I've done everything right but apparently not because my jobs hangs when trying to upload GCS.

The weird thing is that I used to be able to deploy jobs to Dataflow and now I suddenly can't anymore. I've searched for hours. Does anyone know why this job won't start?

[image]

Comment: Tried the quickstart and it works fine for me using Dataflow runner. I just noticed that for your value on `--temp_location` the gcs path is missing a `/` before the colon`:`  hence Dataflow created a temporary bucket for it. 1.) Can you try `--temp_location gs://wordcount_test_bucket/tmp/` and check if it will resolve the issue? 2.) If not can you try running it in a different region? 3.) Also if it created a job in GCP Console > Dataflow > Jobs, can you add the logs found there in the question?

Comment: @RiccoD I added the missing `/` and changed the region to europe-west1. It still hangs when it's uploading the dataflow_python_sdk.tar file. And it doesn't even create a job in the console but it does upload the pickle file... I'm so confused. :(

Comment: Other things that I've done: 1. Created new service account with Owner rights and put the credential json file in my working directory, then set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIAL variable. 2. Created new virtual environment with the apache-beam[gcp] package.

Comment: If you check Cloud Logging, are there any related logs to Dataflow or GCS? Not sure if it has any effect but did also you run `pip install wheel` prior to installing `apache-beam[gcp]`?

Comment: Yes I also did the `pip install wheel`. I'm now in the process of draining other jobs (that had errors) so I can see more clearly if I get any for the wordcount example.

Comment: Just a long shot, could it be that it cannot proceed since it can't spawn workers due to lack of resources?

Comment: I'm getting no logs in the cloud logging... Not even a log that a worker spawns or that I do not have enough resources...

Comment: Extra note: When I use the DirectRunner I can upload the output fine to GCS.

Comment: I think I just can't reach the Dataflow API because when I disable the API and then try again it hangs at the same spot.

Comment: I'm becoming desperate... Revoke gloud auth, use gcloud auth login, created new service account, reset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS multiple times... Enable/Disable Dataflow API. And all it does is hang at the same spot. Terrible exception handling of Dataflow service!

Comment: @Stanko I see that you're running the command at your local machine. Consider following the same steps on Cloud Shell and see if you can isolate problem. Maybe the issue comes from your environment.

Comment: I've spin up a new Ubuntu VM and now it works... My guess is that it had something to do with my virtual environment. I created virtual env like this `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 env` because standard I hade Python3.9 and beam doesn't support that. Now I created a venv like this `python3 -m venv env` because my fresh Ubuntu has python 3.8 installed. I can finally deploy again... Spent countless hours on this, not wishing this on my worst enemies. Hope nobody has to go through crap like this. Beam or Dataflow should alert there is something wrong with the versions. End of rant.